# ICE Connection Failed on Android when subscriber drops the call

Tags: java, android, webrtc, janus, rtcpeerconnection

I am using Janus-Android-Gateway of [Crossle](https://github.com/crossle/janus-gateway-android) for WebRTC Videoroom calling.

Call is working fine.

Only problem is ICE Connection failure when any opponent peer or subscriber leaves the call.

ICE Connection gets disconnected for that peer. Which is fine. But then in 10 seconds of that. ICE Connection state failed received in PeerConnection onIceConnectionChange() callback.

No Clue why it triggered this failure.

Same code of Crossle is working fine in iOS Swift code.
ICE disconnected when other peer leaves VideoRoom but ICE Connection doesnot fails as in case of android.

Following logs flow can help in understanding.

These are from the state when opponnent peer drops call

```
janus: event - plugin -> unpublished
IceConnectionState newState is: DISCONNECTED
onIceDisconnected()
janus: hangup
janus: event - plugin -> leaving
subscriberOnLeaving()
janus: success
janus: detached
IceConnectionState newState is: FAILED
```